# Problema para crear una preview de imágenes

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen

quiero hacer una preview de imágenes como lo que tiene Amazon cuando abres un producto y tienes las imágenes en pequeño, y al hacer hover sobre cada una, esta se visualiza en grande.

Había pensado en hacer algo con CSS, pero al estar las imágenes que se van a ver en grande dentro de un div, no śe si es posible hacer un selector para ello, así que opté por usar un event listener en JS.

```
<div class="item__image-container">
    <img class="item__image item__image--1 item__image--small" src="1000w-opt.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="item__image item__image--2 item__image--small" src="2000w-opt.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="item__image item__image--3 item__image--small" src="3000w-opt.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="item__image item__image--4 item__image--small" src="" alt="" />
    <div class="item__image-container-preview">
        <img class="item__image item__image--1 item__image--preview item__image--current" src="1000w-opt.jpg" alt="" />
        <img class="item__image item__image--2 item__image--preview" src="2000w-opt.jpg" alt="" />
        <img class="item__image item__image--3 item__image--preview" src="3000w-opt.jpg" alt="" />
        <img class="item__image item__image--4 item__image--preview" src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

La función que creé lo que hace es que cuando ***item__image--small*** es hover, entonces ***item__image--preview*** tenga opacity = 1

```
let imageSmall = document.getElementsByClassName("item__image--small");

for(i = 0; i < imageSmall.length; i++) {

    var imagePreview = document.getElementsByClassName("item__image--preview")[i];

    imageSmall[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        imagePreview.style.opacity = "1";
    });

    imageSmall[i].addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
        imagePreview.style.opacity = "0";
    });
}
```

El problema es que no sé cómo lograr que cuando llame la función en la imagen 1, corresponda a la preview de la imagen 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta esto.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="item__image-container">
  <img class="item__image item__image--1 item__image--small" src="ada.png" alt="" />
  <img class="item__image item__image--2 item__image--small" src="ae.png" alt="" />
  <img class="item__image item__image--3 item__image--small" src="adx.png" alt="" />
  <img class="item__image item__image--4 item__image--small" src="ardr.png" alt="" />

  <div class="item__image-container-preview">
      <img class="item__image item__image--1 item__image--preview item__image--current" src="ada.png" alt="" />
      <img class="item__image item__image--2 item__image--preview" src="ae.png" alt="" />
      <img class="item__image item__image--3 item__image--preview" src="adx.png" alt="" />
      <img class="item__image item__image--4 item__image--preview" src="ardr.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let imageSmall = document.getElementsByClassName("item__image--small");

    for(i = 0; i < imageSmall.length; i++) {
        let imagePreview = document.getElementsByClassName("item__image--preview")[i];

        imageSmall[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            imagePreview.style.opacity = "1";
        });

        imageSmall[i].addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
            imagePreview.style.opacity = "0";
        });
    } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo unico que cambio respecto al código que tenías fue:

```
let imagePreview = document.getElementsByClassName("item__image--preview")[i];
```

así, al declarar imagePreview tipo let, se crea de manera local y no global.
espero sea lo que estabas buscando, a mi me funciono bien, intentalo tu.

Comment: Asombroso! gracias!

Comment: Con mucho gusto :)